# Table - problem with two lines (NEW)

Tags: tables, floats, rotating, booktabs, threeparttable

Dear TeX Stackexchange

I have one issue, when I create my table. As you can see on the picture below, the three black lines don't go to the right but stops under (10):

[image]

My text look like this:

```
        \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[english]{babel} 
        \usepackage{layout}
        \usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} 

        % Different usepackages
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage[lf]{MinionPro} %% MinionPro
        \usepackage{icomma}
        \usepackage{setspace}
        \setstretch{1.10}
        \usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
        \usepackage{graphicx}

        % Page margins
        \usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=3.4cm,bottom=3.4cm]{geometry}

        % Tabular
        \usepackage{threeparttable}
        \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
        \includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}}
        \renewcommand{\TPTnoteSettings}{\footnotesize}
        \renewcommand{\TPTnoteLabel}[1]{#1}

        \usepackage{float}

        % Rotate
        \usepackage{pdflscape}

        \begin{document}
   \begin{landscape}      
            \begin{table}[H]
            \begin{threeparttable}
            \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
            \medskip
            \renewcommand\tabcolsep{1pt}  % Set this to some very small value ...
            \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ @{} p{2.4cm} 
                 @{\extracolsep{\fill}}   % and let LaTeX provide the necessary "fill" amount
                 *{12}{S[table-format=2.3]} @{}}
            \toprule
            \emph{?} 
            & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Room1} 
            & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Room2} 
            & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Room3} 
             \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-13}
            & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} 
            & {(5)} & {(6)} & {(7)} & {(8)}
            & {(9)} & {(10)} & {(11)} & {(12)} \\
            \emph{Dep.\ var.}
            & {Elec} & {Elec} & {Elec} & {Elec} 
            & {Elec} & {Elec} & {Elec} & {Elec} 
            & {Elec} & {Elec} & {Elec} & {Elec} \\
            \midrule
            \emph{Undep.\ var.}\\
            Electricity
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}}  
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}}  
            \\
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            \\
            Ohm 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}}  
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00\sym{***}}  
            \\
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,00)} 
            \\ 
            \cmidrule{1-1}
            R\textsuperscript{2} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00}  
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00}  
            \\ 
            N 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{000} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{000} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{000} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{000} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{000} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{000} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{000} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{000}
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{000} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{000} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{000} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{000}
            \\ 
            \bottomrule
            \end{tabular*}
            \end{threeparttable}
            \end{table}
        \end{landscape}
        \end{document}
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. If you can see, what I am doing wrong or help me by fixing it - I would appreciate that help very much!

EDIT: New Table

```
    \begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
    \medskip
    \begin{tabular*}{0.82\textwidth}{
      @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
      l
      c
      S[table-format=3.0]
      S[table-format=3.0]
    }
    \toprule
    & {Randomized$^{\pm}$} & {Electricity$^{\mp}$} 
     \\
    \midrule
    Power    &  &  &  \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ One      &   16,4 pct.\sym{**}             & 19,5 pct.    \\ 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ Two      &   16,8 pct.\sym{***}               & 15,0 pct.    \\ 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ Three      &   19,2 pct.           & 17,8 pct.    \\ 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ Four     &   16,6 pct.             & 16,7 pct.    \\ 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ Five      &   16,4 pct.             & 15,3 pct.    \\ 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ Six     &   14,7 pct.             & 15,7 pct.    \\ 

    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: The `\toprule` stops also (above the column with `10`)

Comment: Where can you see that? What should I write instead?

Comment: Look at your screen shot: The (thicker) `\toprule` stops shortly before the 10 - column

Comment: The content is much larger than \textwidth.

Comment: The table content is too wide, it bleeds into margins... the rules are still correct

Comment: Hmm. I see. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @A.F. Either a smaller font or you have to get rid off those multiple `***` stuff (whatever that means there), perhaps you can reduce the column widths significantly. Or redesign your table

Comment: I need those stars - and I need the table to be width. Can you maybe help me by fixing my problem?

Comment: @A.F. How about using a side ways table, i.e. landscape, just for this table?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post a complete example including the document class and packages etc. If we are talking about fitting stuff to a particular page, it matters a whole lot what the page dimensions are, what the layout dimensions are, which font and which fontsize etc. A4 in 12pt Helvetica is a different question from US letter in 10pt Venturis ADF. But we also need to know what kind of solution you want. A smaller font size? Rotate the table?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - the best option for me, would be if it was fitted to the landscape - so it goes from left to right, but how do I do that?

Comment: @cfr - I have added the whole preamble . Does it work?

Comment: you can't have `\begin{landscape}` before `\begin{document}` If you want the entire document landscape remove the `landscape` environment and use the `landscape` documentclass option.

Comment: Ah, sorry. The begin \begin{landscape} is of course after begin{document}

Comment: It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. Adding the preamble and the table separately isn't so helpful.

Comment: Dear @Andrew. I have now updated my post. Can you maybe help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had to replace `\textwidth` with `\linewidth`: \textwidth is the global textwidth (in portrait mode), while \linewidth is the `current` line width – which means `\textheight` when you're in a landscape environment. I took the opportunity to simplify your code, removing all this plethora of `\multicolumn`s.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}

% Different usepackages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lf]{MinionPro} %% MinionPro
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.10}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Page margins
\usepackage[hmargin=3.5cm, vmargin=3.4cm]{geometry}%

% Tabular
\usepackage{threeparttable}   
\newcommand\sym[1]{\textsuperscript{\rlap{\,#1}}}
% \includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}}
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteSettings}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteLabel}[1]{#1}

\usepackage{float}

% Rotate
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
  \mbox{}\vfill
  \begin{table}[H]
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
      \medskip
      \renewcommand\tabcolsep{1pt} % Set this to some very small value ...
      \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{ @{}l
          @{\extracolsep{\fill}} % and let LaTeX provide the necessary "fill" amount
          *{12}{S[table-format=1.2, table-space-text-pre=(, table-space-text-post=)]} @{\hphantom{\textsuperscript{***}}}}
        \toprule
        \emph{?} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Room1} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Room2} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Room3} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-13}
        & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} & {(7)} & {(8)} & {(9)} & {(10)} & {(11)} & {(12)} \\
        \emph{Dep.\ var.} & {Elec} & {Elec} & {Elec} & {Elec} & {Elec} & {Elec} & {Elec} & {Elec} & {Elec} & {Elec} & {Elec} & {Elec} \\
        \midrule
        \emph{Undep.\ var.}\\
        Electricity & 0,00\sym{***} & 0,00\sym{***} & 0,00\sym{***} & 0,00\sym{***} & 0,00\sym{***} & 0,00\sym{***} & 0,00\sym{***} & 0,00\sym{***} & 0,00\sym{***} & 0,00\sym{***} & 0,00\sym{***} & 0,00\sym{***} \\
        & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} \\
        Ohm & 0,00{\sym{***}} & 0,00\sym{***} & 0,00\sym{***} & 0,00\sym{***} & 0,00\sym{***} & 0,00\sym{***} & 0,00\sym{***} & 0,00\sym{***} & 0,00\sym{***} & 0,00\sym{***} & 0,00\sym{***} & 0,00\sym{***} \\
        & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} & {(}0,00{)} \\
        \cmidrule{1-1}
        R\textsuperscript{2} & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 \\
        N & {000} & {000} & {000} & {000} & {000} & {000} & {000} & {000} & {000} & {000} & {000} & {000} \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular*}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
  \vfill\newpage
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Space between two and three stars.
[image]

**Added** New code for the second table: I redefined the `sym` command sio that it doesn't change the alignment of the cells, and I simplified the code (only three columns):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}

% Different usepackages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lf]{MinionPro} %% MinionPro
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.10}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Page margins
\usepackage[hmargin=3.5cm, vmargin=3.4cm]{geometry}%

% Tabular
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\newcommand\sym[1]{\textsuperscript{\rlap{\,#1}}}
% \includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}}
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteSettings}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteLabel}[1]{#1}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
    \medskip
    \begin{tabular*}{0.82\textwidth}{
        @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
        >{\hphantom{Power}}l
        S[table-format=2.1]
        S[table-format=2.1]
      }
      \toprule
      & {Randomized$^{\pm}$} & {Electricity$^{\mp}$}
      \\
      \midrule
      \llap{Power} & {pct.}& {pct.}\\
      One & 16,4 & 19,5 \sym{***} \\
      Two & 16,8 & 15,0 \\
      Three & 19,2 & 17,8\sym{**} \\
      Four & 16,6 & 16,7 \\
      Five & 16,4 & 15,3 \\
      Six & 14,7 & 15,7 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Bernard. I have two questions. If I would like to use 1 or 2 stars, do I just need to add "@{\hphantom{\textsuperscript{ONEstart}} and @{\hphantom{\textsuperscript{TWOstarrs}}" after this @{\hphantom{\textsuperscript{THREEstars}}? I can't put the stars in here.

Comment: Second. If I don't have any numbers to fill out in "Ohm" under (1), is it possible for me to put "-" a line in that field? If I put a line there, it just disappear

Comment: The `\hphantom` are here because I did  not take the stars into account for the formatting of the `S` columns (I had to, in order to have a correct placement of `)` in the row below).  So in the last column, the stars go into the margin if we use `@{}`. . So you have to use `@{\hphantom{\textsuperscript{max number of stars in the last column}}}`.

Comment: Second question: I would use `{--}` (I mean an endash, between brackets, to have it centred in its column.

Comment: Wups. I made an edited to your post. I have tried to write three stars in that column, but as you can see in the picture - the space between numbers and stars are different depends on how many stars.

Comment: Your second answer works perfect -thank you!

Comment: Is there an easy way to switch "dot" to "comma" between 0","00  - last question

Comment: `\sisetup{output-decimal-marker=,}`, or use the argument of `\sisetup`  as an optional argument to the `S` qualifier in the table. For the problem of the spacing with the spars, I'll try to find what happens. I note also the right parenthesis with `0.19` has a larger spacing. If there are only a few such problems, you may in the meantime play with `\!` or `\,`, or even `\mkern`x`mu`.

Comment: Also, for the parenthesis, you should in tables use `tabular` numbers, since Minion Pro has the 4 kinds of numbers.

Comment: I have edited my post, where I have copy and pasted a tabular layout, which work with the stars and the comma - without adding anything

Comment: If I write \, it makes a huge space

Comment: If I wrote the command in the edited post - there are no extra space, when I use 1, 2 or 3 stars. There are no problem with comma as well. Is it possible to change the commands before, so it fit to the table, that I edited

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26766/discussion-between-bernard-and-a-f).